# Reordering values across the axes on tile plot on R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on creating a tile plot in R. I have a dataset as follows, with all combinations of durations and education values.

```
duration        education        count
-----------------------------------------
less-than-5        unknown        25
less-than-10       high           50
more-than-10       medium         34
unknown            low            54
```

I created a tile plot as follows but want to reorder the values on each axis so that it makes more sense (unknown, low, medium, high - on education) and similarly of duration as well.

```
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = duration,
                     y = education)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = count))
```

Comment: There are two options, 1) You can encode `duration` and `education` as factors with levels in the correct order or 2) You can set the `scale_(x|y)_discrete(limits = c(...))` where `...` are character vectors with the categories in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

It could be OK to create *ordered factors* from `duration` and `education`:

```
data %>%
    mutate(
        duration = factor(duration, levels = c("unknown", "less-than-5", "less-than-10", "more-than-10"), ordered = TRUE),
        education = factor(education, levels = c("unknown", "low", "medium", "high"), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = duration,
               y = education)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = count))
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Data:**

```
data <- structure(list(duration = c("less-than-5", "less-than-10", "more-than-10", 
"unknown", "less-than-5", "less-than-5", "less-than-10"), education = c("unknown", 
"high", "medium", "low", "low", "medium", "low"), count = c(25L, 
50L, 34L, 54L, 28L, 23L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```